# Firebase & Backbone: Trouble using uid as a key

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, firebase, backbonefire

I created logins and unique todo lists per user using Firebase and TodoMVC as proof of concept for another project. I'm using Firebase and Google to log users in and when things are working, they get a unique persistent todo list.

Everything works (I think) when the user is already logged into Google via their browser.

The problem happens when they aren't. Instead of their todo list, or a blank one under their user id, they see the todo list of an undefined user until they hit refresh, then things work again. The Firebase url  doesn't see their uid until they hit refresh. If you're logged in to Google, you can replicate the error by opening an incognito window.

You can see the errors in my code at http://lacyjpr.github.io/todo-backbone, and my repo at https://github.com/lacyjpr/todo-backbone

This is my authentication code:

```
 // Authenticate with Google
 var ref = new Firebase(<firebase url>);
  ref.onAuth(function(authData) {
    if (authData) {
      console.log("Authenticated successfully");
    } else {
      // Try to authenticate with Google via OAuth redirection
      ref.authWithOAuthRedirect("google", function(error, authData) {
        if (error) {
          console.log("Login Failed!", error);
        }
      });
    }
  })

// Create a callback which logs the current auth state
function authDataCallback(authData) {
  if (authData) {
    console.log("User " + authData.uid + " is logged in with " +               authData.provider);
  uid = authData.uid;
} else {
  console.log("User is logged out");
 }
}
```

This is the code that gets the UID to use as a firebase key:

```
// Get the uid of the user so we can save data on a per user basis
var ref = new Firebase(<firebase url>);
var authData = ref.getAuth();

if (authData) {
  var uid = authData.uid;
  console.log(uid);
}

// The collection of todos is backed by firebase instead of localstorage
var TodoList = Backbone.Firebase.Collection.extend({

// Reference to this collection's model.
model: app.Todo,

// Save all of the todos to firebase
url: <firebase url> + uid,
```

Thanks in advance for any advice you can offer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `.getAuth()` before a user is authenticated.

Your app heavily relies on the `uid` to work properly. So in your case you would want to kick off the Backbone portion of the app once user has successfully authenticated.

You could modify your app.js to only kick off if the user is authenticated.

```
// js/app.js

var app = app || {};
var ENTER_KEY = 13;

$(function() {

  var ref = new Firebase(<firebase url>);
  var authData = ref.getAuth();
  if (authData) {
    ref.authWithOAuthRedirect("google", function(error, authData) {
      if (error) {
        console.log("Login Failed!", error);
      } else {
        // kick off app
        new app.AppView();
      }
    });
  } else {
     new app.AppView();
  }

});
```

**While this will work, it isn't the ideal solution.** But there is no other option since you don't have a login screen.

Ideally, you'd want to provide the user a place to login, and then you'd have access the `.getAuth()` value.

Also, don't worry about storing the `uid` on the `window`. `.getAuth()` is the cached user, so there's no network call to get the data.

Comment: Can you create a Plnkr or JSBin that reproduces this problem? It doesn't have to be the full-blown app, but just a sample that shows your problem.

Comment: Did you update the github page website? I'm still seeing the same code.

Comment: Ah I see what's going on. I've updated my answer to simplify the login process. The callback of the login is lost in the async nature of `onAuth`. In your case you only need to use the login callback. If you want to listen to `onAuth`, you should do that within the `AppView`.

Comment: Ah, I keep forgetting you don't have a log in button. That's really the solution here. You shouldn't throw up the redirect when the page loads. It confuses the user and it adds a lot of complexity to manage in the code, but my updated answer should help you for now.

Comment: David -- looks like I need to add a login button. Do I also need to wire that up to the .getAuth() code?